# UIBezierPath round edges?

Tags: ios, drawing, uibezierpath

Im drawing some lines and I noticed that when the edges get at a certain angle it generates a sharp edge like this: [image: pointy edge]

What I want it to draw: [image: round edge]

How do I do this? I have looked through the documentations but I dont seem to find anything im looking for. Or is there a way to turn that auto-edge-generating off?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

UIBezierPath's have a property called `lineJoinStyle`. Set it to `kCGLineJoinRound` and it will draw as you want it.

```
UIBezierPath *myPath = ...
myPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
```

Comment: Wow, a million points to you! A decade later and this is super valuable. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

kCGLineJoinRound property on a UIBezierPath can be called in Swift by:

```
myPath.lineJoinStyle = .round
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CGContextSetLineJoin`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGContextSetLineJoin) to set your drawing context's join parameter to `kCGLineJoinRound`, before you stroke the path. This is documented in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF105).

If you are drawing a UIBezierPath, you can also set the path's `lineJoinStyle`, which may be easier.