# How to draw corner curves in a square UIBezier in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I created a square using UIBezier Path, i know we can draw rounded rectangle using rounded rect function in bezier path, but the issue i am facing is different. Every time i give corner radius to CAShapeLayer where bezier path is assigned, it removes some part of bezier path.

That's why i was thinking i should draw bezier using curves to give on corners. The CAShapeLayer takes width and height of a UIView which i have already added in Storyboard.

I tried adding corner radius to shapeLayer(in which bezierPath.cgPath is assigned) and then masking the layer to bounds. It does make the corners of my bezier square rounded but it removes some pointy tips from bezier. I wanted all 4 corners to be rounded.

```
let customShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
customShapeLayer.path = createBezierPath().cgPath
customShapeLayer.cornerRadius = 6.0
customShapeLayer.maskToBounds = true
```

The output i am getting when i don't mask the shapelayer to bounds is like this:

[image]

And when i mask the shapelayer to bounds, this is what i get:

[image]

(It's just a rough representation of what i have seen, it might not look like rounded corners )

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18167327/6783598

Comment: @BenRockey The layer is over a UIView, if i give cornerRadius to layer or add lineCapStyle, nothing will happen unless i mask the layer to bounds. Masking the layer to bounds makes those 2 spikes disappear, of course there will be lineCapStyle as round but at the same time those spikes won't be there anymore.

Comment: check this tutorial. https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/